# How to create model allowing infinite submodels in django?

Tags: django, model-view-controller

Im creating a site where you can write down your goals, you should be able to split every goal into subgoals if chosen, and allow those subgoals to be split into subgoals infinitely.

This code below shows what i came up with first for the models, the first model is for creating a goal, the second model can either either be a subgoal of the goal or a subgoal of the subgoal.
But it seems like a really bad way to go around this problem.

Django semi-newbie BTW...

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Goal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, editable=False)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['user', 'title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " - " + self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.title.replace(' ', '-').lower()
        super(Goal, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class SubGoal(models.Model):
    goal = models.ForeignKey(
        Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        "SubGoal", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return self.goal.title + " - " + self.title
        except:
            return self.parent.title + " - " + self.title
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to build something that will look like a binary tree: where you have goal1, goal2 and goal2 is sub goal of goal1 and so on goal3 of goal2. if that is the case I think you can achive this in one model by using self join and two more fields that will tell you if the goal is subgoal, goal or both

Comment: Yes, exactly!..

Comment: Also look at [Trees and Graphs](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/trees-and-graphs/) I can recommend mptt and treebeard.

Comment: Thanks man, i will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `ForeignKey` to self. If the `ForeignKey` is `NULL`, then that goal has no parent, otherwise it refers to the parent:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
django.utils.text import slugify

class Goal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        related_name='subgoals'
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'title'], name='user_title')
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        if self.parent_id is None:
            return '{}-{}'.format(self.user.username, self.title)
        else:
            return '{}-{}'.format(str(self.parent), self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Goal, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Good answer, but I wouldn't use SET_NULL here, but rather CASCADE, PROTECT, or something like `SET(find_closest_parent)` to prevent subtrees being pulled up to top-level.

Comment: Thanks so much man, that does the trick! :) Slugify is a nice addition. Do you think it would be possible to show this in a tree like structure in the template?